# How to change Visual Studio/Resharper autocomplete default selection?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

I'm using **Visual Studio 2010** (with **resharper**) and 2012.

Each time I'm using `Console.WriteLine`, when I type the **'.'**  the `WriteLine()` is automatically selected. Selecting Tap it places the cursor after the ';' instead of inside the brackets where I want it.  It's just annoying to have to use the mouse to get between the brackets or backspace several characters when there is already an option for `WriteLine(string)` which does exactly what I want.  But to select it I would have to use the down-arrow keys to get there.

Is there any way to configure what the default selection should be?

Having `WriteLine(string)` as the default would save hundreds of keystrokes or mouseclicks.

Answer (score 1):

If its not more trouble than its worth, then you could reset your Resharper settings (assuming you are using at least Resharper 6.1)

```
Go to Resharper -> Manage Options...
Click the "Reset All Settings" button.
```